# Django oscar - customizing StockRecordForm form

Tags: python, django, django-oscar

I am trying to customize `StockRecordForm` in django-oscar administration. What I have:

1. Forked `dashboard` app, also `catalogue_dashboard`
2. Included new `StockRecord` attribute in `models.py`
3. Updated `forms.py` like this:

```
from oscar.apps.dashboard.catalogue import forms as base_forms

class StockRecordForm(base_forms.StockRecordForm):


    class Meta(base_forms.StockRecordForm.Meta):
        fields = [
            'partner', 'partner_sku',
            'price_currency', 'price',
            'num_in_stock', 'low_stock_threshold', 'new_attribute',
        ]
```

Part of my `INSTALLED_APPS` looks like this:

```
#'oscar.apps.dashboard.apps.DashboardConfig',
#'oscar.apps.dashboard.catalogue.apps.CatalogueDashboardConfig',
'mikeapps.dashboard.apps.DashboardConfig',
'mikeapps.dashboard.catalogue.apps.CatalogueDashboardConfig',
```

But modification is not showing up. Is there anything else I should modify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allright, I am surprised that in this case I have to actually modify template to show the new fields (unlike `ProductForm` etc.), I presumpted that all chosen attributes will be shown in forms automatically, but I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

About that need to update the templates as well,

follow steps,

1. Create a **templates** directory under your project.
2. Give templates path to your setting.py
   [image: setting.py]
3. Create the **oscar** directory under the template directory then the dashboard directory then **catalogue**,
4. Create file name product_update.html

should look like this:
[image: update template for stock in oscar]

Then extend 'product_update' template from your oscar lib

```
{% extends 'oscar/dashboard/catalogue/product_update.html' %}
{% load form_tags %}
{% load i18n %}
```

then use `{% block stockrecords_content %}` and copy all code from it and edit it to your need.
for example your `new_attribute` add `<th>{% trans "new_attribute" %}</th>` and

`<td>{% include "oscar/dashboard/partials/form_field.html" with field=stockrecord_form.new_attribute nolabel=True %}</td>`

it will work fine.